# MSTest vS StructureMap: Certain indirectly-referenced dlls are not getting scanned by structure-map even though they do exist on disk

Tags: mstest, structuremap

First things first here is a link to a demo project that show-cases the issue at hand:

```
https://github.com/dsidirop/MTestStructureMapIssue.git
```

In a nutshell when tests are getting run from within Visual Studio everything is fine. If we attempt to run the same tests using MTest.exe like so:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MsTest.exe"    /nologo  "/testcontainer:MTestStructureMapIssue.Tests.dll"
```

Then we get the following error inside the constructor of the test-class 'DummyTest':

```
 StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException: No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'MTestStructureMapIssue.Dummy.Contracts.ISomeDbContext'

 There is no configuration specified for MTestStructureMapIssue.Dummy.Contracts.ISomeDbContext

 1.) Container.GetInstance<MTestStructureMapIssue.Dummy.Contracts.ISomeDbContext>()

    at StructureMap.SessionCache.GetDefault(Type pluginType, IPipelineGraph pipelineGraph)
    at StructureMap.Container.GetInstance[T]()
    at MTestStructureMapIssue.Tests.DummyTest..ctor() in C:\VS\MTestStructureMapIssue\Code\MTestStructureMapIssue.Tests\DummyTest.cs:line 23.
```

The culprit behind this error message appears to be that MSTest.exe for some reason prohibits certain dlls from getting scanned because it doesn't even copy them over to the "test-folder" despite the fact that we do use the attribute:

```
[DeploymentItem(@"MTestStructureMapIssue.Dummy.dll")]
```

How can one overcome this elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround to cater to the needs of MSTest (given the fact that [DeploymentItem] doesn't do the trick):

```
 public DummyTest()
 {
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles("../../.."))
        {
            try
            {
                File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(".", Path.GetFileName(file)));
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
...
```

This snippet will copy over any and all files (dlls, configs etc) from the "bin" directory over to the test folder employed by MSTest.exe.